Error Division Zero when hit endoint with rspec rails
I have some test with rspec, but when i run that test, appear error division zero like images below, can someone help me?
This my code
This my result when i run rspec
there is no error code in controller and i expect that test running well
code spec
post "/auth/signup_post", params: {
  email: "coba1@gmail.com",
  password: "coba123",
  password_confirm: "coba123",
  name: "Coba Coba",
}, headers: {
  "Content-Type" => "application/json",
  "Accept"       => "application/json",
}

Failur messages
F

Failures:

Authentication signup post
Failure/Error:
post "/auth/signup_post", params: {
email: "coba1@gmail.com",
password: "coba123",
password_confirm: "coba123",
name: "Coba Coba",
}, headers: {
"Content-Type" => "application/json",
"Accept"       => "application/json",
}
ZeroDivisionError:
divided by 0


addition info when i add new success file, name test in it replace with dot (.)
Name test in it replace with dot (.)

can you paste code here, not images?

@AntonBogdanov code has been updated
